# How to write this self joined query with distinct based on the inner join relationship using the query builder?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder

I have an entity `Place` that can hold many different types of places, particularly in this case "cities" and "states", where each "city" can hold a reference to the same table pointing to a parent "state".

I have another entity `Office` with a many-to-one relationship to `Place`, but because of domain constraints, an office will only be linked to a "city", never to a "state".

I have to write a query to get all states where we have one or more offices, but only those.

In plain SQL, the query works out easyly enough:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT states.*
         FROM offices o
            INNER JOIN places cities ON cities.id = o.place_id
            INNER JOIN places states ON cities.parent_place_id = states.id
WHERE p.place_type = 'city'
```

This works, and we get exactly what we need.

**But** I need (I would prefer) to write the query using the query builder. This is "base" query, but we need to conditionally apply several more filters, which would make using the QB **much** cleaner and manageable.

Currently we are using a [Native Query](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/native-sql.html), but this means that we need to manipulate the SQL string before we call `em::createNativeQuery()`, which is cumbersome.

```php
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('states')->distinct()
           ->from(PartnerOffice::class, 'o')
           ->innerJoin('o.place', 'p')
           ->innerJoin('p.parentPlace', 'states')
           ->where("p.placeType = 'city'");
```

But this gives an error about:

> SELECT DISTINCT': Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias

How can we make this query work?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to figure out the query you should build without seeing the entities (at least for me). Eg: do you have a mappedBy field? But I think your problem is that you are fetching no information from PartnerOffice while it is your root entry (from). Either change your `->select()` for a `->addSelect` but that will fetch the entire PartnerOffice entity for each record and you distinct might not work as expected, or use the Place entity as your root entry and flip the logic.

Let's assume your entities' relations are bidirectional. Something like this should do it (but you might need to change it for the real entities and fields names).

```
$this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->distinct()
    ->from(Place::class, 'p')
    ->join('p.cities', 'c')
    ->join(PartnerOffice::class, 'po', Join::WITH, 'po.place = p')
    ->andWhere('p.placeType = \'state\'');
```

Comment: I didn't mention the inverse relationship because it doesn't exist. The only relationships are the ones mentioned, which I thought made posting the entities redundant. Nevertheless, your code is mostly correct. I only had to change the second joint to `->innerJoin(PartnerOffice::class, 'po', Join::WITH, 'po.place = p')`. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think you have posted an incomplete base sql query (`WHERE AND`) and you made an alias `p.place_type` which is not defined above in the query.
However, from your statement, I think you can try the query below,

```php
$qb->selectRaw('DISTINCT s.states')
           ->from('offices as o')
           ->join('places as c', 'c.id', '=', 'o.place_id')
           ->join('places as s', 's.id', '=', 'c.parent_place_id')
           ->where('c.placeType', 'city')->get();
```

By default, `->join()` refers to inner join in queryBuilder.

Source:

1. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#inner-join-clause

Comment: Thanks for the "WHERE AND" correction, that was a copy paste typo. But you are answering about eloquent when the question is about doctrine.

Comment: paceType is not an alias. Is a `Place` property. Not much right in this answer I'm afraid. Thanks anyway (BTW, I can't vote neither up or down).